# Turn definitions into rules

Tags: replacement, rule, code-generation, meta-programming

I know that this seems to be unnecessary, but here I have a bunch of assignments, like around 50, and I want to create rules for all these to have the freedom to apply these rules only on certain expressions. However I can't find an efficient way to do this. Please help.

Here's an example:

I want to turn the following assignment expressions:

```
a = Cosh[ξ0];
b = Sinh[ξ0];
d = Coth[ξ0];
c = 1/((Sinh[ξ0])^2*Cosh[ξ0])^(1/3);
...
```

into a rule:

```
subabcd = {
   a -> Cosh[ξ0],
   b -> Sinh[ξ0],
   d -> Coth[ξ0],
   c -> 1/((Sinh[ξ0])^2*Cosh[ξ0])^(1/3)
   };
```

Problem is I got more then 50 of the definitions..

`Clear` is also not efficient because I have to put in all those names of the variables.

Comment: Consider using the text editing capabilities in the notebook front-end----search and replace.

Comment: Have you seen `DownValues` and `OwnValues` and so forth?

Comment: @PaulCommentary hmm, it worked,  I'll also have to replace the semicolon into comma. I guess that's the most efficient way for now. Thank you for reminding me of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
torulelist = 
  Function[a, Unevaluated[a] /. {Set -> Rule, CompoundExpression -> List}, HoldAll];

torulelist[
 a = Cosh[ξ0];
 b = Sinh[ξ0];
 d = Coth[ξ0];
 c = 1/((Sinh[ξ0])^2*Cosh[ξ0])^(1/3)]

(*
{a -> Cosh[ξ0], b -> Sinh[ξ0], d -> Coth[ξ0], 
 c -> 1/(Cosh[ξ0] Sinh[ξ0]^2)^(1/3)}
*)
```

Comment: Worked really well! Thank you!

Comment: I have to ask, how to type in those greeks?? I can only copy it from other posting.

Comment: @YingZhang Try this extension: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1044/1871 or this site: http://steampiano.net/msc/

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: @YingZhang Hi, if the post indeed solves your problem, please consider accepting it.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ It's not a bad idea to wait for a while (say 24 hours or even longer) before accepting to see if someone comes up with a better solution.

Comment: @xzczd :) Okay.